# Reference solution config from project config

Tags: c#, .net, config, appsettings

I am new to .NET but taking over a solution from another developer.  The solution has 12 separate projects and each project has 9 AppSettings.config files based on different test and production environments.  Each of these enviornment config files have some appsettings that are always the same across all config files. I would like to have 1 solution/global config file that can be referenced within each of the 9 project config files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have global and local settings at the same, that is very difficult to achieve.

If all config files are the same, you could link the files from one source.

https://andrewlock.net/including-linked-files-from-outside-the-project-directory-in-asp-net-core/

Can you reference an other config file for a specific section: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource?view=netframework-4.7.2

This way you could share the same connectionstrings across all projects.

For more difficult things you will have to setup something yourself.